# How do i write a rspec for a process method in following code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Basically i want to make sure that method_1 and method_2 should be called from process method.

```
  def process
        begin
          method_1  if some_condition
          method_2  if some_condition      
          self.update_attribute(:status,DONE)
        rescue=>e
          self.update_attribute(:status,ERROR)
          p e
        end
    end

def method_1
#some code
end

def method_2
#some code
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
it "should call #method_1" do
  YourClass.should_receive(:method_1)
  YourClass.process
end

it "should call #method_2" do
  YourClass.should_receive(:method_2)
  YourClass.process
end
```

I'm assuming those are class methods.

If those are instance methods, you could do `YourClass.any_instance.should_receive(...)` or `your_instance.should_receive(...)`

See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames for more info.

**Edit:**

`should_receive` will also stub the method. This will cancel the stubbing and call the method:

```
YourClass.should_receive(:method_2).and_call_original
```